# Convert array to string in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I have a function in controller like this. I need to insert result from `$data1['hasil1']` to tampilInduk .

```
public function sikap(){
    $person=$this->session->userdata('idperson');
    $data1['hasil1']=$this->M_Guru->tampilNik($person);

    $data2['hasil2']=$this->M_Guru->tampilInduk($data1);
    $this->load->view('sidebarGuru');
    $this->load->view('navbarGuru');
    $this->load->view('kompetensiSikap',$data1+$data2);
}
```

I have model code like this

```
public function tampilInduk($data1){
        $this->db->select('induk');
        $this->db->from('kelas b');
        $this->db->join('siswa_kelas c','c.namakelas= b.namakelas','c.thnakademik=b.thnakademik','c.kdtingkat=b.kdtingkat','right');
        $this->db->where('nik',$data1);
        $data = $this->db->get(); //mengambil seluruh data
        return $data->result();
    }

public function tampilNik($person){
        $this->db->select('nik');
        $this->db->from('guru');
        $this->db->where('idperson',$person);
        $data=$this->db->get();
        return $data->row()->nik;
    }
```

But the error said that the variable need to convert to string first .could u help me how to convert array to string for my case?

Comment: first explain what `$data['hasil1']` prints and then explain what column of that should be in the where statement in the next function.

Comment: `I need to insert result from $data1['hasil1'] to tampilInduk .` where is your insert query

Comment: `$data['hasil1']` this variable just get 1 value

Comment: `print_r($data['hasil1']);` what is it?

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [nik] => 4144222 ) ) @Alex

Comment: use `$data['hasil1'][0]->nik`

Comment: `$data2['hasil2']=$this->M_Guru->tampilInduk($data1);` @pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public function sikap(){
    $person=$this->session->userdata('idperson');
    $data1['hasil1']=$this->M_Guru->tampilNik($person);

    $data2['hasil2']=$this->M_Guru->tampilInduk($data1['hasil1']);
    $this->load->view('sidebarGuru');
    $this->load->view('navbarGuru');
    $this->load->view('kompetensiSikap',$data1+$data2);
}


   public function tampilInduk($nik){
        $this->db->select('induk');
        $this->db->from('kelas b');
        $this->db->join('siswa_kelas c','c.namakelas= b.namakelas','c.thnakademik=b.thnakademik','c.kdtingkat=b.kdtingkat','right');
        $this->db->where('nik',$nik);
        $data = $this->db->get(); //mengambil seluruh data
        return $data->result();
    }

public function tampilNik($person){
        $this->db->select('nik');
        $this->db->from('guru');
        $this->db->where('idperson',$person);
        $data=$this->db->get();
        return $data->row()->nik;
    }
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Try again. Forgot something. updated

Comment: i've tried both method above but the result still same A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you are getting `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [nik] => 4144222 ) ) ` correct?? in which case you are assigning it to `$data1['hasil1']` and in the first ex i gave you are passing it to the function that way which means (if you are getting the above array) then `$data['hasil1'][0]->nik` is the correct way of getting it. are you using my updated code I changed something earlier...

Comment: can you 1) `print_r($data1)` in the **function** and report that 2) add  the function `tampilNik` to your question

Comment: `print_r($data1)` Array ( [hasil1] => 4144222 )

Comment: alright check my updated answer i didn't know you were going to use `row()`

Comment: i've put tampilNika in my question

Comment: yes ive already updated as per that. should work fine now

Comment: is it working??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->db->where('nik',$data1['hasil1']);` instead of `$this->db->where('nik',$data1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem:

```
public function tampilInduk($data1) {
        $this->db->select('induk');
        $this->db->from('kelas b');
        $this->db->join('siswa_kelas c', 'c.namakelas= b.namakelas', 'c.thnakademik=b.thnakademik', 'c.kdtingkat=b.kdtingkat', 'right');
        $this->db->like('nik',$data1['hasil1']);
        $data = $this->db->get(); //mengambil seluruh data
        return $data->result();
    }
```

I hope it will help.